# Open a webpage and enter a username and password via CLI

Tags: command-line, login, authentication, browser, web

Ultimately, I want to use a bash script to automatically open and log into a website.

I was wondering if I could use the `curl` or `elinks` commands to log in to a website and then somehow export that to a web browser, or if I could change the preferences on the Firefox web browser to log in with preset credentials.

I was not successful in these attempts, and do not know if they are even possible. I'm open to any other methods of accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 1):

For simple things you can use curl.  There is a way in curl to get fill in a form with the -F option but many things are more complex than just submitting a single form.  For that, you need to go through multiple steps to get to where you want to be.

I would write a perl script and use the WWW::Mechanize module.

http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.75/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm

Here is an example from that page:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( $url );

$mech->follow_link( n => 3 );
$mech->follow_link( text_regex => qr/download this/i );
$mech->follow_link( url => 'http://host.com/index.html' );

$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 3,
    fields      => {
        username    => 'mungo',
        password    => 'lost-and-alone',
    }
);

$mech->submit_form(
    form_name => 'search',
    fields    => { query  => 'pot of gold', },
    button    => 'Search Now'
);
```

Comment: I don't think either suggestion addresses the question.  The OP asked about using a web browser... neither mechanize or curl ever invoke a browser... they just speak http.